# Get hostname and threadId of SQL procedure caller

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Given a C# .NET Console application calling a SQL stored procedure from within two separate threads I know it's possible to view the calling hostname in SQL using SELECT HOST_NAME() but is it possible to identify the calling thread?

I'm trying to identify when a procedure is executed by thread A for example;  I can't make a any code changes and so I'm hoping there is something available in SQL; details of the currently executing procedure / connection?

I've looked at SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests for example but nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: No.  Connection is made through network and a remote connection will not contain the process info.

Comment: And `HOST_NAME()` is spoofable very easily. Maybe set a `SESSION_CONTEXT` when you create the connection on the client side